# AVPlayerITem playbackBufferEmpty not always changing under iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm having a problem with the playbackBufferEmpty property under iOS 5 (on the simulator).

I'm observing the property in an effort to indicate to the user when the player is in a buffering state.    The problem is that I do see the property change from 0 to 1, but it never appears to change back from 1 to 0.   I know that the playbackBuffer is no longer empty because the player starts playing again and continues with no problems.

Under iOS 6, everything works as I would expect it to.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

If there is a better strategy for displaying a "buffering" message, I'd love to find it.

Thanks

-Jason

Comment: playbackBufferEmpty cannot be really used to indicate buffering to the user, simply because playback buffer is too small so on EDGE your user would probably never get out of the "buffering" loop. In reality it's better to buffer N seconds before continuing playback. So I think the best strategy is to use playbackBufferEmpty to detect when data is stalled (because this event invoked before "rate" change so when playback stops you already know why) and use loadedTimeRanges changes to figure out when to continue playback, i.e. hide buffering message etc..